# Minimum Path Sum: is it possible to solve it using DP given negative value(s) in the grid?

Tags: dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization

Question description taken from leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-path-sum/

```
Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers,
find a path from top left to bottom right, which minimizes the sum of all numbers along its path.

Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

One Example:
Input: grid = [[1,3,1],
               [1,5,1],
               [4,2,1]]
Output: 7
Explanation: Because the path 1 → 3 → 1 → 1 → 1 minimizes the sum.
```

I tried to set some negative values in the grid, and it seems the transformation function still works.

```
dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]) + grid[i][j]
```

Can anyone come up with a case to prove that DP won't work for this question if there is/are negative value(s) in the grid?

Comment: The very strong constraint "you can only move down or right" makes it work regardless of negative values. Note that all paths from top left to bottom right that only move down or right will have the exact same length. So for instance: (1) Start from a grid that can have negative values; (2) Find the minimum value `min` in the grid (`min` will be the largest-amplitude negative number); (3) Create a new grid by subtracting `min` from all values. Then: the new grid has no negative values, and the minimum-sum path in the new grid and in the old grid will be the same paths.

Answer (score 0):

If surely it is mentioned that user can only move down or right then your code perfectly works for negative numbers as well

But if it is given that user can move in any direction and at last should reach the destination then

The above code works only for positive elements
consider the below example

```
grid = [ [1 , 10000,-700,10],
         [2 ,  4   ,9   ,6 ] ]
```

in this the min path  is 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 9 -> -700 -> 9 ->6